Prime-k solution doesn’t go above certain number in c++
Im currently trying to solve the prime-k factor problem, where I have to find the sum of all primes factorial 1-5 ! and then mod(%) to itself. An example would be the prime 7.
(7-1)!+(7-2)!....(7-5)!=...%7.
The answer to this would be 4.
I have to find this answer to the sum of all primes to 10^8. Therefore I have written the following code(which I know I not optimized)!.
#include<iostream>    
#include<vector> 

using namespace std;


bool prime(unsigned long long int n){
    if (n==2 || n==3){
        return true; 
    }
    if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0) return false;
    for (unsigned long long int i = 5; i * i <= n; i += 6) {
        if (n % i == 0 || n % (i + 2) == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

vector<unsigned long long int> Prime_lst(unsigned long long int n){
    vector<unsigned long long int> v {}; 
    for(unsigned long long int i = 5; i<n+1; i++){
        if(prime(i)==1){
            v.insert(v.end(), i); 
        }
    }
    return v; 
}

unsigned long long int factorial(unsigned long long int n)
{
    unsigned long long int res = 1;
    for (unsigned long long int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        res *= i;
    return res;
}
unsigned long long int prime_p(unsigned long long int n){
    unsigned long long int c = 0; 
    for(int i = 1; i<6; i++){
        c += factorial(n-i); 
    }
    return c%n; 
}

unsigned long long int sum_prime_p(unsigned long long int n){
    unsigned long long int k = 0; 
    vector<unsigned long long int> prime_lst = Prime_lst(n); 
    for(unsigned long long int i = 0; i<prime_lst.size(); i++){
        cout << k << " "; 
        k += prime_p(prime_lst.at(i)); 
    }
    return k; 
}

int main(){
    //vector<unsigned long long int> v = Prime_lst(100); 

    //for(auto i=v.begin(); i<v.end(); i++)
    //{
    //  cout<<" "<<*i << " ";
    //}
    cout << sum_prime_p(100); 

    return 0;
} 

I have to get 480, but I always get 305 due to ints being 32 bits therefore I have used unsigned long long int. But I still can't get the right answer. Hope someone can help:)!

Please [edit] and use a descriptive and unambiguous title.

Are you sure a unsigned long long can contain 97! for example?

I think you're missing a few more long's in your type... joke aside for calculations like this you would need a big integer library

@PepijnKramer i know it’s horrendous to look at hahaha. Just got desperate and changed the variables everywhere. I will try and find a library for big integers

You don't need a big integer library. Instead you should perform all operations modulo n since you don't really need that final big number, but only the value modulo n.

unit64_t would be much easier to work with than unsigned long long int

@WeijunZhou Thanks for adding that insight, I missed that bit math :)

@AlanBirtles this still dosent work

I think you probably don't need to compute manually (7-1!)+(7-2)!....(7-5)! with some math.

Are you sure it's (7-1!) and not (7-1)!?

"I have to find the sum of all primes factorial 1-5 ! and then mod(%) to itself." << Could you please rephrase this sentence? It's very unclear what "the sum of all primes factorial" means, and your example with 7 doesn't really make it clearer.

If all you're interested is the result mod m, then you should make all your calculations mod m (as long as you only do multiplications, subtractions and additions)., In particular, replace your function factorial(n) with a function mod_factorial(n, m), in which the line res *= i; is replaced with res = (res * i) % m;

Please clarify what you mean by "find this answer to the sum of all primes to 10^8". Does it mean that you find this formula [(p-1)!+(p-2)!+(p-3)!+(p-4)!+(p-5)!]%p  and you sum it up for all primes p <= 100000000 ? That would come to somewhat more than 480. Could you provide an "original link" to your question. (There are many other definitions of k-primes.)

BTW, you would never have to add five separate factorials: mod(p) or otherwise.

@lastchance here is a link to the problem https://projecteuler.net/problem=381 . I just used an example of the function for all primes from 5 to 99, since it would give a better example. it would therefore be [(((p_1 -1)!+(p_1-2)!+....)%p_1)+(((p_2-1)!+(p_2-2)!+....)%p_2)+.......+ (((p_n-1)!+(p_n-2)!+....)%p_n)] 

First of all, here is a link to the original problem: https://projecteuler.net/problem=381
Solution with N=100:
Sum( S(p) ) = 480

Solution with N=100'000'000:
Sum( S(p) ) = 139602943319822

You do not need to sum over 5 factorials; you can reduce to 1. For small n it is reasonable to do these modulo p (as already noted). However, for large n you need a faster way. (Sorry to have to turn the maths into an image).

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

using INT = unsigned long long;

//======================================================================

vector<int> sieve( int nmax )
{
   vector<bool> is_prime( 1 + nmax, true );
   is_prime[0] = is_prime[1] = false;
   for ( int i = 4; i <= nmax; i += 2 ) is_prime[i] = false;
   int imx = sqrt( nmax + 0.5 );
   for ( int i = 3; i <= imx; i += 2 )
   {
      if ( is_prime[i] )
      {
         for ( int j = i * i; j <= nmax; j += 2 * i ) is_prime[j] = false;
      }
   }

   vector<int> primes;
   for ( int i = 2; i <= nmax; i++ ) if ( is_prime[i] ) primes.push_back( i );
   return primes;
}

//======================================================================

INT ipow( INT X, INT p, INT M )
{
   INT result = 1;

   while ( p )
   {
      if ( p % 2 ) result = ( result * X ) % M;
      X = ( X * X ) % M;
      p /= 2;
   }

   return result;
}

//======================================================================

int main()
{
// const int N = 100;
   const int N = 100'000'000;
   auto primes = sieve( N );
   INT SumS = 0;
   for ( auto p : primes )
   {
      if ( p < 5 ) continue;
      INT S = ( ipow( 24, p-2, p ) * ( 2 * p - 9 ) ) % p;
      SumS += S;
   }
   cout << "Sum( S(p) ) = " << SumS << '\n';
}

//======================================================================


Thank you so much for the answer! It's actually better with the math image, since it's quite interesting. Can you recommend something that teaches you this? im very interested in math and CS and would really like to learn how to solve big problems like this. Sorry for the late comment. @lastchance

Well, it’s really a problem of number theory - specifically primes and modular arithmetic - rather than computer programming. In that respect, Marcus du Sautoy’s “The Music of the Primes” wouldn’t come amiss. And you could always end up solving the biggest unsolved hypothesis about the primes that there is ….

thank you very much for the help and for the inspiration!
